# How to join a domain if both Server and User machines are virtual

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, vmware

I am learning Network Administration. 
In our University lab, everything is setup with different virtual machines connected to each other, And I am trying to create the same scenario at home since most of the required Windows are free for us to download and use.

I have downloaded and installed Windows Server 2012 in VMWare and also installed Windows XP Professional.

Both the machines are setup in VMWare Workstation with the network connection type of VMware as `NAT`.

Now I setup the Domain Controller in Windows Server 2012 with the domain name `testServer.com`, and also setup the DHCP server.

The DHCP server IP ranges are, `192.168.10.1` - `192.168.10.250`
Default gateway I set to: `192.168.10.1`

Now, I configured Windows Server's own IPv4 address as, `192.168.10.201` and preferred DNS server is the same IP address.

I am confused here, if I have changed Windows Server IP configuration, doesn't that mean that it is not connected to the VMWare NAT network anymore ?

I started my Windows XP virtual machine and now I want it to join the domain on Windows Server 2012, but I don't know how am I supposed to do it since both the machines are virtual and not connected to each other using any switch or anything.

Could anyone guide me if that even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup both of your virtual machines to be connected as `Host only` mode instead of `NAT` in your VMWare's Network adapter option.

You also need to make sure that your server ip address `192.168.10.201` is excluded from being distributed. This can be done from your DHCP pool settings.

You should then be able to join the domain just fine.